# GMenu Iterate a GMenu in python, get content

Tags: python, gtk

I'm trying to pull the content out of Gio.Menu, but it's confusing me.

Here is (simplified) code that creates the menu object

```py
from gi.repository import Gio.Menu

menu = Gio.Menu()
menu.append("Hello world", "window.hide")
```

I can see from [this example gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/3v1n0/58c13a8bac4008a82cd66084fc71c95a/raw/fa767fd83503bcc117b0bddaf662781e980f46e9/glib-menu-model-window-introspection.py) that I can use a combination of get_n_items, and various things to iterate the menu, but haven't got it yet as it's pretty complex (I'm pretty sure I don't need to link to the `change-items` event for instance)

Comment: What content are you looking for?

Comment: The label, and the action.

Comment: What is the action? Could you link some docs? I am quite familiar with retrieving the label .

Comment: What's the best way of retrieving the label ?

Comment: Oh, no. It looks like a Gio.Menu is fundamentally different from a Gtk.Menu. The code I use for a Gtk.Menu is [here](https://github.com/benreu/PyGtk-Posting/blob/dfa367a3eaef830efeba44549f6a2abf01c7fb5a/src/quick_command.py#L49).

Comment: Cheers - it's pretty confusing finding out all these differences, I've got a rough idea I'll post here later.